# openfire(3.9.3) messages not storing in mysql database

Tags: xmpp, openfire, livechat, real-time-updates, stream-management

i m using xmpp (openfire 3.9.3 ) for real time messaging between mobile applications but m not able to get history 
so i installed monitoring services plugin and activated its chat and group chat archiving in settings but still m not get any message in messagearchive table and even not in archive tab of servers its not storing any message

after little research i got to know about open archive plugin so i downloaded it and try to install fot hat after rename the zip and browse it in upload plugins option and its giving message upload successfully 
but still its not showing in plugins options and not messages stored yet

any idea whats the issue

any idea how to it in xep or monitoring services or open archive

Comment: after installing monitoring plugin, you need to enable store `one to one` chat in admin panel. You will find this option in archive settings. :)